# Pull live prices from web page

Tags: java

I need to pull prices from a web page in order to use them inside a Java app.
Any hint about how to do this would be welcome.
An example of page:
http://www.eurexchange.com/market/quotes/orderbook_en.html?symbol=FGBL&name=Euro-Bund Futures

Comment: hava a look at the sites sourcecode. find out how they do it using javascript, then translate that to java.

Comment: If you want a reliable, stable and legally correct solution, you may consider to use a broker platform like InteractiveBrokers which has Java APIs. Market prices might cost you something, depending on the exchange. But the result will be optimal.

Comment: @clamp: that's what I want to do ultimately. Any tutorila about how java plugin works that could help pull the right functions and call them? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a look at source and it getting data from "http://www.eurexchange.com/orderbook/production/FGBL:201109.gz"
interval 1 i think means i sec.

But like amnesyc said mite not be a good idea.

Comment: This brings a file with loads of data that apparently contain what I'm looking for. I'll try to parse it and see but thanks for the hint!!!

Comment: I changed gz to txt and I got exactly what I needed! Thank you very much everyone for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Taking data that was not meant to be exposed to an external system is not a good idea.
You have to search for a feed provider that will give you an API based on json, xml, or what every.

Or as an alternative you can get a client side API like iframe.

I believe that if you try to access data that was not meant to be given free, the provider will make you life harder....

For a good api with stable systems and accurate data you'll need to pay some $$$

Comment: This data is 15 minutes delayed and should be free to use (99% sure).

Comment: I just want to pull the data for some tests, not building anything very important here.

Answer (score 1):

The linked page is rendered using applets.  Your best bet is to hook into whatever information the applets are using.  And on that subject, I note that the home page of the site mentions RSS feeds.

Comment: Yes, this is the sort of solution I'm looking for. Since they're using java to get the data and display it, any chance I can bypass the browser and use those functions staright from java?